# Can regular ON/OFF solenoid valves be turned into a proportional valve just by changing the control electronics?

Tags: power, current, driver, magnetics, solenoid-valve

I was wondering whether it was possible to make a proportional valve out of a regular ON/OFF solenoid valve by characterizing the current vs the flow rate and then driving the solenoid using a resulting interpolated lookup table flow rate -> current? I'm expecting that proportional valves are optimized somewhat, but would the loss in performance be that significant? If so, by how much roughly and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no guarantee that the valve will operate in steady state for some partial current ranges. Not even that it can be made to do so closed loop.

The ON/OFF solenoid valves may have mechanical response bandwidths that exceed the electrical bandwidth. That means that even if you were to have flow feedback sensor of adequate bandwidth, and close the control loop, the coil assembly may well not have enough bandwidth without exceeding the voltage and thermal ratings. Or the range in which it is controllable is rather limited when compared to the full-flow.

The ON/OFF solenoid valves are only guaranteed to have well-defined behavior in the ON and OFF state. Proportional valves are purposefully designed to have some sort of usable open-loop response. There is always some mechano-fluidic means provided to stabilize such valves, so that for a constant control input, after a disturbance the flow converges on steady state without excluding any such steady state. There are designs that could be called inherently stable, but that's still because of designed-in negative feedback. It's just a matter of how much effort was spent on making the thing passively stable.

Some ON/OFF valves use internal positive feedback, and to stabilize them you'd need an external control loop agile enough to completely neutralize that. While not always impossible, the implementation would usually be so costly and fiddly as to negate any benefit from using a cheaper ON/OFF valve.  Such valves, when you sweep the control current, will essentially "snap" from OFF to ON, without any intermediate state. They may behave the same way on the ON to OFF trajectory, or they may not. They are not linear because they don't have to be, and usually the nonlinearity and positive feedback are used to benefit the performance of the valve, e.g. speed up its response when switching states.

In other words: you may find some types of solenoid ON/OFF valves that may be amenable to open-loop control, where you'll still need to characterize the changes in behavior due to aging and wear. That takes quite a bit of costly engineering time. But also expect to find ON/OFF solenoid valves that may only be controllable with high bandwidth feedback. And some of them cannot be made stable no matter what the external feedback is.

So, while what you're trying is not impossible, it definitely requires plenty of engineering time to first of all find a model that will even work at all, and then qualify it product for such use. Nothing guarantees that the manufacturer won't change something in the design in the meantime that will make the "upgraded" product unsuitable for proportional control.

If you want to do it as a one-off kludge, in some temporary test jig or something like that, and can get it to work reasonably - sure, why not. But every question as to "will it work?" or "why doesn't it work?" will have to be answered by spending your engineering effort on it. You'll have to be using an awful lot of these valves for that cost to result in any savings. The manufacturer is not only unlikely to provide you with any support for such use, but if the application involves high liability, they may even refuse to sell to you.

Answer (score 2):

No. An on/off valve usually has some internal positive feedback -- as the solenoid pulls in, the inductance and force increases and it pulls in faster. Thus it cannot remain in a '½' in position with a static DC current. In theory a complex control system could regulate the current to maintain this position, but that would require a high level of sophistication.

A simple valve may also have hysteresis because of magnetic remanence of the iron core. Again, this precludes an open-loop control scheme.